# Get the row count

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, excel

I have an excel file, I want to get the row count of that particular file in html. I have to mention it in my index.html

To be More Precise:
Html code should read the excel file, get the row count store it in a variable. so that I can display by the variable in my index.html

The Below script I'm trying is uploading the file. but I need to read the file from locally by giving its path and get the row count and store it in a variable

```
<table id="tblCustomers" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 90px">Customer Id</th>
            <th style="width: 120px">Name</th>
            <th style="width: 90px">Country</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>X</td>
            <td>United States</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Y</td>
            <td>India</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Z</td>
            <td>France</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>Russia</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br />
<br />
<input type="button" id="btnGetCount" value="Count Rows" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
        $("#btnGetCount").click(function () {
            var totalRowCount = $("#tblCustomers tr").length;
            var rowCount = $("#tblCustomers td").closest("tr").length;
            var message = "Total Row Count: " + totalRowCount;
            message += "\nRow Count: " + rowCount;
            alert(message);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please add all code you've attempted to solve this to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: First google search results seem to do exactly what you need: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/reading-a-excel-file-using-html5-jquery/

Comment: [Above Link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/reading-a-excel-file-using-html5-jquery/) will take the excel as input in the browser itself. but I'm looking for it should take path of the file in code itself.